# editText.getText().append in fragment is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

i use customlistener in adapter(used for recyclerview). if view is clicked, i handle the event in fragment.
(the event is editText.getText().append)
problem is my customlistener is work well but i can append texts and when i check edittext by using editText.getText,then there is not thing...

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
final View root=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment,container,false)
editText=root.findViewById(R.Id.editText);
ad.setOnItenListener(new webTomainadaper.OnItemClickListener(){
public void OnItemClick(String s, int position){
editText.getText().append(s);
}
})}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
editText.setText().append(editText.getText().append(s));
```

What you were doing is that you are only requesting the text inside the editText , not updating the view (editText)